# integration testing of hibernate with OpenSessionInViewFilter paradigm

Tags: hibernate, integration-testing, open-session-in-view

I use spring and hibernate with a ria technology called ZKOSS and use the OpenSessionInViewFilter paradigm,

I have integration tests to test features like

1) Entity is loaded into the UI (has lazily loaded entities)
2) Updates are made to it on the UI -- (In the tests UI is replicated through a series of setter method calls)

3) Update button pressed and entity is updated

and more often than not my tests pass.

However when i really start using the application, I end up getting lazy loading exception, because

1) Entity is loaded into the UI   -- Loaded in session1 (proxy points to session1)

2) Updates are made to it on the UI -- (In the tests UI is replicated through a series of setter method calls)

3) Update button pressed and entity is updated -- (try to access a lazily loaded entity) and get an lazy loading exception

I want to catch such exceptions in my integration tests, any ideas ? ... is my approach correct here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/), that can record clicks, typing and other actions you perform and then replay them as a test.

Comment: I was looking for something that i could use in code, selenium and the like bring a host of other problems example ... sometimes they cannot find the textfield at runtime and so on,